# Transcendentality of the $\log$ of the golden mean

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers, golden-ratio

We know that $\phi$, the golden ratio, is algebraic. Is it known whether $\log(\phi)$ is algebraic?

Thank you!

PS. I am not in number theory, so I apologize in advance if this is obvious.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$\log (\phi)$ is transcendental. The [Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) implies that if $\alpha$ is a nonzero algebraic number, then $e^\alpha$ is transcendental. So since $\phi$ is algebraic, $\log (\phi)$ is transcendental.

Comment: Whoops. The statement of Lindemann-Weierstrass is slightly stronger than I remember.

Comment: The trick is to have forgotten the statement entirely, so you have to look it up.